# What is correct sqlType used for setNull()

Tags: java, jdbc

I am having an spring MVC project with Mysql DB. In an table I want to set NULL value for column having data type BIGINT. Code that I used to set NULL is:

`ps.setNull(1,java.sql.Types.NULL);`

OR

`ps.setNull(1,java.sql.Types.BIGINT);`

NULL value is inserting If I use any of above statement but what is correct SqlType to be used? NULL or BIGINT.

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull(int,%20int)) says "You must specify the parameter's SQL type." for `setNull`. Therefore, I believe you should pass the value `java.sql.Types.BIGINT`.

Comment: And what's your issue with that?

Comment: Why to use parameter's SQL type? What is difference in using BIGINT and NULL whereas both are inserting NULL in DB.

Comment: I couldn't really find any documentation apart from the link in my answer. Perhaps you could take a look at the source code if that is possible to see the possible difference?

Comment: Oh Okay, That's only I want, I got that we have to use parameter's SQL type but why it should be like this.What is difference in it when both are inserting NULL.